# How to write directly to memory in C#

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am working on a serial port comms project. There is a piece of hardware sending signed 16 bit integer values, which are being received in to a C# PC application.
Each value is sent over two bytes, least significant byte first.

The performance of the is critical, so I'm looking at ways of reducing processing.

The C# Serial Port object provides a method ReadExisting, which returns the current buffered values as a string.
It also provides a method Read which can accept a byte array which is then populated with the bytes in the port buffer.

If I read all the values in to a byte array, I then have to join the two bytes together to get the 16 bit number.

I'm intrigued by the string returned from the ReadExisting method.
If I create an array of short (short[] MyValues), I could then get the memory location of the array, and simply write the string to that location. As long as I ensure the bytes are sent in the correct order, I could then simple read the 16 bit values when needed.

Alternatively, I could *possibly* create two arrays, one an array of shorts, the second an array of bytes twice the size of the first, both with the same memory location.

However, "here be dragons". I have no experience with C# and this level of memory access.
Some brief googleing suggests this is possible - this article has some interesting information:
https://www.developerfusion.com/article/84519/mastering-structs-in-c/

Before I head off down this particular rabbit hole, does anyone have any suggestions on how to achieve this level of memory manipulation?

Thanks

Comment: Use a structure with an overlay.  The overlay can allow reading/writing in byte[] and int16[].

Comment: @jdweng, that will only work if the processor is little-endian

Comment: You probably nee to _pin_ your chunk of data.

Comment: @JimRhodes The C# project is 15 months in, so switching isn't an option. The C# project is WPF based, so will only run on W7/8/10. All X86 based, so endianness is not an issue.

Comment: @jdweng, that looks promising, I'll investigate further during the week.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what baud rate are you using and just how much data is involved here?

Comment: The bottleneck is not the conversion from byte array to integer array. You are making a pointless optimization.

Comment: @JimRhodes That's what triggered this. Changes to code showed doubling the baud rate from 57600 reduced one of the transfers from 6.5 seconds to 6.4 seconds for around 16kB. This is a once or twice a session occurrence.

Then there is around 1200 bytes at up to 10Hz.

The biggest one currently is 1 MB at around 8 minutes.

Some of this code is 20 years old. I have control of both ends of the comms, so if I'm going to rip it to pieces, I may as well do as much as I can.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan There's some odd maths going on at the moment to convert the two bytes to 16 bit integers, which is part of the bottle neck. 
If I'm taking it all to pieces anyway, why not improve it as much as possible?

But you are right, we will spend some time finding where the bottle necks actually are.

Comment: Serial port comms will be many orders of magnitude slower than converting byte array to 16 bit int array. Just use `Marshal.Copy`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Agreed. However, as mentioned above, doubling the baud rate from 57600 reduced one transfer of 16 kB from 6.5s to 6.4s, so there's definitely a serious code issue.
Thanks for the input, much appreciated.

Comment: I doubt very much that your conclusion is correct. There's no way code to convert 16kB of bytes into a 16 bit int array takes anything more than microscopic time. Try it. Try calling `Marshal.Copy` with 16kB of data and see how long it takes. You are going to make life way more complicated than you need if you attempt to implement what you suggest in the question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I think you've misunderstood.
I'm not saying the array copy is the problem. Right now, all I know is there is a problem somewhere. It's not the serial transfer, as doubling the baud rate had a negligible effect on the transfer time.
So I need to look at the rest of the code. Currently, there's a lot more than a simple array copy. 
As I'm rewriting all this, I want to get as many options together to test as I can.

Comment: Well don't try to put two arrays in the same memory location is my advice.

Comment: Assuming you are using 8 data, 1 start and 1 stop, 57600 should give you 5760 characters per second. 1MB should only take about 3 minutes. I think you should also look at your transmitter for problems.

Comment: You need a Queue and Threading.  You should use the DataReceived event to build your string then once you have the whole string Enqueue it with the Queue class in which on a separate thread you can do whatever math operations you need without hurting the performance of the serial port.

Answer (score 0):

Try an overlay

```
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int NUMBER_OF_BYTES = 100;
            ByteInt16 byteInt = new ByteInt16();
            byteInt.data = new byte[NUMBER_OF_BYTES];
            byteInt.data2 = new UInt16[NUMBER_OF_BYTES / 2];

            byteInt.data = Enumerable.Range(0, NUMBER_OF_BYTES).Select(x => (byte)x).ToArray();

            UInt16[] results = byteInt.data2.Select(x => (UInt16)x).ToArray();

        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
        public struct ByteInt16
        {
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public byte[] data;
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public UInt16[] data2;
        }
```

Comment: You can only overlay simple types like int, double, etc. You can't overlay arrays.

Comment: @ David Heffernan  : I've done this a lot recently and it works with arrays, but you have to call the constructor (with size) for each item in the overlay before you used it.  Once the size is set is works perfectly.

Comment: No you have not. Were it true that you had done this, you've have encountered a runtime as the marshaler failed to deal with a type that it cannot marshal.

Comment: This does not take into consideration the endianness of the processor and therefore should not be considered an acceptable solution.

Comment: @JimRhodes That's the least of concerns given that when you attempt to run a program with this code you get a runtime exception.

Comment: If the bytes do not need swapping, than there is no issue.  The application may just be passing data and not generating the data in c#.  if input is iin correct order than output will also be in correct order.

Comment: @jdweng It doesn't bother you that your code leads to a runtime exception as soon as you try to pass such a type to the unmanaged method? How can you be fine with that? Or do you think I am making that up?

Comment: @David Heffernan You seem to be misunderstanding the purpose of this code. There is no marshaling, `[StructLayout]` also affects the managed layout. Overlaying two references and violating type safety this way is possible. While things can of course go badly wrong when you're executing methods of type `A` on what is actually an object of type `B`, it won't crash unless you're actually corrupting data or do something that would involve the method tables etc.

Comment: @kalimag OK, I hadn't appreciated that this is not involved in a marshaling operation. However, it's still not right. For instance, suppose we have `buffer.data = new byte[6];
            buffer.data2 = new UInt16[3];` then what value would you expect for `buffer.data.Length`?

Comment: It doesn't really. Look how the length of both arrays is always the same?

Comment: The offset of both array are zero so you have an overlay.  A Int16 when converted to bytes the length is always double.

Comment: From what I see, `byteInt.data2 = new UInt16[NUMBER_OF_BYTES / 2];` causes what was allocated by `byteInt.data = new byte[NUMBER_OF_BYTES];` to be released. If you assign a value to the byte array before allocating `byte2`, the value is lost. Also, it looks like `results` ends up with 100 entries not 50.

Comment: @jdweng why not debug your program and see that the length isn't what you think. It's a mess.